# How to determine the statistical significance of a score from a general population?

Tags: r, probability

Let's say I got a reading of 5 for a given measurement.

For a random population, I got the following dataset of readings:

```
random <- c(2,2,1,1,5,76,3,89,35,66,77,22,99,100,0,34,67,88,95)
```

I want to determine the probability of getting a reading equal or less than my reading of 5 based on this random population.  Could you mind to teach me how to do so?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a list of every number in the dataset, you can use a [randomization test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_test#Permutation_tests) (also known as permutation test).  This is where you enumerate every possible outcome, and simply count the ones that fit your criteria.

For instance, in your example, there are 19 numbers in the dataset.  7 of them are less than or equal to 5.  So the chances that you will draw a number from this dataset that is less than or equal to 5 is simply 7/19, or roughly 37%

The permutation test is a specific instance of a more general class of methods called resampling.

If, however, you don't have a list of every item in the dataset, you can still use inferential statistics to calculate the approximate probability using a sample's standard deviation and Z scores.  If this is the case, let me know, and I will explain in more detail...

Comment: my 19 number dataset cannot represent every item in the dataset.

Comment: using the same experimental condition, I have another sets of data for a larger sample population (~100 data).  This population is different from my 19 number dataset.  Can I use it as the random data set for probability calculation?  Could you mind to teach me how to do so?

Comment: To calculate Z-score, do I have to make sure my raw data (i.e. my 19 number dataset) fits normal distribution?

Comment: @evd The permutation test is usually used if you literally have a list of the every item in the data.  But you can use it on a sample  as well, in the same method I described. Unlike my previous example, though, the probability won't be exact. It's accuracy will depend on the size of the sample and the size of your population.

Comment: @evd yes, in order to use Z scores, your data must be normally distributed. but you can apply similar logic if you have another known distribution.  If this doesn't help answer your question, perhaps you could revise your question with the exact information you have about your data?

Comment: Thank you Jeff, I will figure out how to add the data, as it is a large dataset with 500000 data.

Comment: I tried to fit my random dataset to all options in fitdistr and fgev, however, none of them fit well.  Since my random dataset did not fit norm dist.  it seems to me that I cannot use Z-score too.  Anyway, i will figure out how ask it question in a better way.  Thanks a lot.